# Assign variable to Dataset, same value for each position along dimension

Tags: python-xarray

When I assign a number to a new variable in an array

```
ds = xr.Dataset({'data': (('x'), [1, 2, 3])})
ds['new'] = 5
```

I get

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 3)
Dimensions without coordinates: x
Data variables:
    data     (x) int64 1 2 3
    new      int64 5
```

But, what I'd like is:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 3)
Dimensions without coordinates: x
Data variables:
    data     (x) int64 1 2 3
    new      (x) int64 5 5 5
```

How do I get this behaviour independent of the length of x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`xarray.full_like`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.full_like.html#xarray-full-like) can be useful for this purpose:

```py
ds["new"] = xr.full_like(ds.data, 5)
```